# GetCurrentDirectory() - почему каждый 2ой байт в szPath это \0?

Tags: c++, winapi

Эта функция должна записывать в szPath путь, откуда был запущен бинарник. У меня она возвращает путь, но, каждый 2ой байт в szPath это `\0` , в итоге код ниже не работает так как я хотел. Адрес запуска бинарника: `C:\Пользователи\z\source\repos\ProjectName\Debug` (автоматом многие проги заменяют `пользователи` на `users` сами, тут не знаю заменяет или нет)

```
char szPath[0x100];
GetCurrentDirectory(0x100,(LPWSTR)szPath);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Довольно странно вы задаете размер массива, вы же в жизни пользуетесь десятичными числами, наверное? Вообще WinAPI определяет специальный символ `MAX_PATH` который определяет максимальный размер файлового пути. Лучше использовать его.

2) Вы задаете буфер для ASCII строки, но используете его с UNICODE версией функции. Правильно будет писать:

```
char szPath[MAX_PATH];
::GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, szPath);
```

Однако этот код не вполне годится если в пути встречаются национальные символы. Поэтому лучше использовать строку UNICODE:

```
WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
::GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, szPath);
```

3) И как вишенка на тортике - функция `GetCurrentDirectory` **не возвращает** путь к исполняемому файлу. Она возвращает текущий каталог, а это нечто другое. Он действительно чаще всего совпадает с каталогом запущенного .exe, но далеко не всегда. Собственно, `GetCurrentDirectory` это пережиток MS-DOS, в многозадачной системе с графическим интерфейсом понятие "текущий каталог" имеет мало смысла. Лучше вообще забудьте про эту функцию, не нужна она.

Для получения пути к своему .exe нужно использовать функцию [GetModuleFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew). Например, так:

```
WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
```

Это немного упрощенно (лучше было бы проверять на ошибку), но работать будет. Для получения именно каталога нужно отыскать первый '\' с конца и отбросить имя файла.
Например, так:

```
*wcsrchr(szPath, L'\\') = L'\0';
```

Comment: Это работает. Про GetModuleFileNameW я не знал(

Answer (score 3):

Так а что ж вы ожидали? Почему у вас в вызове `GetCurrentDirectory` стоит явное приведение `szPath` к типу `LPWSTR`? Очевидно потому, что без него код не компилировался. То есть ваш проект создан в режиме Unicode и `GetCurrentDirectory` возвращает результат в виде "широкой" строки из символов `wchar_t`. Именно эти "широкие" символы вы и наблюдаете.

Зачем вы вообще создали проект в режиме Unicode, если вы не собираетесь работать с "широкими" строками? Вам нужно работать с "широкими" строками или нет? Дальнейшие шаги зависят от ответа на этот вопрос.